# Makefile rebuilds projects on source update

Tags: makefile

Is there a way to have a 'watch' target in my Makefile which would keep looping and rebuilding the project every time the source file gets changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this for my Latex project:

```
.PHONY : monitor 
monitor:
    while true; do \
        inotifywait  -e modify -q *.tex *.cls; make all; \
    done
```

Interesting arguments:

-q for quiet

-r for recursive (if you want to watch the whole **src** folder)

-e to list specific events (if your editor does more file operations and retriggers the build way too often)

--exclude to exclude some (if your **src** folder contains build artifacts) to make sure the build itself will not retrigger this loop (which would be equivalent of an infinite loop without any delays)

More arguments here (inotify tools are amazing):

https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait

Depending on your distribution you might have to install separate package, on my Debian I had to do

> sudo apt-get install inotify-tools